# How can I compare and update the first occurrence in an array overlap?

Tags: c#

Say I have the following 2 arrays...

```
string[] A = ["word1", "word2", "word3"];
string[] B = ["word0", "word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word1", "word2", "word3"];
```

If I want to compare A to B and remove the first occurrence in B so it looks like this...

```
string[] B = ["word0", " ", " ", " ", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word1", "word2", "word3"];
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: Do you really want to replace occurrences with a space character, or do you want to replace with `string.Empty`, replace with `null`, or remove?

Comment: Do you want the first occurrence of the entire sequence of `A`, or just the first occurrence of each element in `A`?

Comment: Do you want to remove the first occurrence in the order of array A, that is first remove word1, then remove the first occurrence of word2, and so on? Or do you not care about the order? Or do you want to remove the entire subarray, the first sequential occurrence of word1,word2,word3?

Comment: @CharlesKeyser the first sequential occurrence of word1,word2,word3 is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward way would be to use [`Array.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187.aspx) to find the first occurrence of each word from `A` in `B`:

```
foreach (var word in A)
{
    var index = Array.IndexOf(B, word);
    if (index >= 0) {
        B[index] = " "; // or whatever other value
    }
}
```

Note this might not work as expected if the replacement value is itself present inside `A` -- if that is possible you should specify what you want to happen.

**Update:** It looks like you want to find and replace the subsequence `A` *as a whole* inside `B`, and not individual elements. This is a very different problem. One (naive) implementation would be:

```
var start = Enumerable.Range(0, B.Length - A.Length + 1)
                      .Where(i => B.Skip(i).Take(A.Length).SequenceEqual(A))
                      .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
                      .First();

if (start != -1)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < A.Length; ++i)
    {
        B[start + i] = " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: @rotaercz said just the **first** occurrence, not all occurrences.

Comment: Oh .. my mistake. It's genious :). You have my plus one :).

Comment: Actually I don't think this holds up when it's like this: string[] B = ["word0", "word1", "word2", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word1", "word2", "word3"]; // when "word3" is absent from the 3rd index.

Comment: @rotaercz: Did you try running it with your example input?

Comment: Yes, I'ved tried. It doesn't work if the first occurrence of the beginning word is partial. For example if the first occurrence starts with "word1" but doesn't have "word2", it removes it from different indices.

Comment: @rotaercz: I really don't know what you are talking about. [Here](http://ideone.com/PyHWxU) and [here](http://ideone.com/9dtE84) is what I see.

Comment: It shouldn't be like that. It should be the first occurrence of the whole sequence. For example if string[] B = ["word0", "word1", "word2", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word1", "word2", "word3"]; Then the result should be: B = ["word0", "word1", "word2", "word4", "word5", "word6", " ", " ", " "];

Comment: @rotaercz: That's a whole different problem -- none of the people who answered could have realized that's what you meant (the example does not help). I 'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I fully support the answer @Jon gave. It is quite fast and succinct and precise.
Still I had a totally different approach, a more functional one, just in case 
by `string[]` you actually wanted to say something more streamy:

Say you have a possibly infinite sequence of strings instead of a primitive array in the role of B. It could be anything: A reading of entities coming straight from a database, a monadic string generator, anything:

```
string[] A = ["word1", "word2", "word3"];
IEnumerable[] B = ...;
```

You could write yourself a nice little extension method:

```
public static class MyHelpers {
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReplaceFirstOccurrencesWithEmpty(this IEnumerable<string> @this, IEnumerable<string> a) {

        // prepare a HashSet<string> to know how many A elements there still exist
        var set = new Hashset<string>(a);

        // iterate and apply the rule you asked about
        // virtually forever (if needed)
        foreach (var value in @this) {
            if (set.Remove(value))
                yield return "";
            else
                yield return value;
        }

    }
}
```

And then you could use it like so, even on your initial A and B arrays:

```
string[] A = ["word1", "word2", "word3"];
string[] B = ["word0", "word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word1", "word2", "word3"];

var cQuery = B.ReplaceFirstOccurrencesWithEmpty(A);
string[] c = cQuery.ToArray();
```

Comment: Great idea @Servy... I made an EDIT :)

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ

```
string[] A = new string[] { "word1", "word2", "word3" };
string[] B = new string[] { "word0", "word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word1", "word2", "word3" };
string[] result = B.Select((word, i) => i <= A.Length && i > 0 && A[i-1] == word ? "" : word).ToArray();
```

Comment: It doesn't work for the first occurrence of the whole sequence. For example if string[] B = ["word0", "word1", "word2", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word1", "word2", "word3"]; Then the result should be: B = ["word0", "word1", "word2", "word4", "word5", "word6", " ", " ", " "];